# extern variables in C and their scope

Tags: c, variables

I am trying to understand this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  extern int a;
  printf("%d\n", a);
  return 0;
}
int a=20;
```

When I run it, the value of `a` is 20. Yet this should be impossible, since the global variable `a` is defined at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `extern` declaration can only be used with variables that are global. It tells the compiler that the global variable is defined elsewhere, and asks the linker to figure it out.

In your code, `extern int a` refers to the `a` defined at the bottom of your example. It could have been equally well defined in a different translation unit.

As others have pointed out, the initialization of `a` takes place before `main()` is entered.

Comment: does the linker automatically figure it out, or do i have to specify it?

i mean for multiple C files i have to make a "Make file" so the linker can link each of the files

Comment: @Rave: You have to link all the relevant files together. Using `make` is one way to automate this process.

Answer (score 2):

Not a problem. By declaring the variable as `extern` you are promising the linker it is defined else where part of current or other source files at global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Initialization of global variables occurs before `main()` is called.

So even if the initialization `a = 20` is located beneath the implementation of `main()`, it's always executed first, so it can be used at program start (assuming you fittingly declared the variable in scopes where it's to be used using `extern int a`).

Comment: Strictly speaking, `int a=20` is not assignment but initialisation.

Comment: If it isn't declared as **extern**, `a` can not be in the scope of main function. http://ideone.com/BNXQs

Comment: `a` isn't declared in `main()` *at all* in your example, @Mahesh. What are you trying to bring across?

Comment: @Linus Kleen Probably, I understood you wrong. Just because initialization of `a` happens even before main doesn't mean it can be used at program start. I was trying the convey the same in the example.

Comment: Ah. Ok. I added a small postamble to eliminate the misunderstanding.